# What does humor-challenged mean?

Tags: meaning, humor, political-correctness

When describing a person as humor-challenged, what does it mean?

Comment: The format *xxxx-challenged* has been around for at least a century, but it's really taken off in the last couple of decades. Contrary to what @Barrie says, I don't think it was just a passing fad - one of the most common is [intellectually-challenged](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intellectually+challenged&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (i.e. - "thick, stupid"), which I don't think is falling into disuse at all yet. But arguably the format is becoming something of a cliche nowadays.

Comment: It means someone who doesn't laugh at my jokes.  It is obviously a fault of theirs and not of my jokes.

Comment: The first word is usually an adverb rather than a noun. A noun sat there doesn't make a lot of sense, e.g. "I'm car challenged". Jocularly challenged perhaps

Comment: @GEdgar: How is it a fault of theirs when they come from a different background, or are not familiar with the language you are using?

Comment: @Tim: You are humor-challenged!

Comment: @GEdgar: I am so flattered!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It must describe someone who lacks a sense of humour. Humour is a big challenge for such people: they struggle to see that anything is funny. Such phrases were quite popular a few years ago. Someone short would be called *vertically challenged*, someone fat would be called *circumferentially challenged* and so on.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Literally, does it mean such kind of persons challenge humors told by others, because they don't understand the humors? (2) Are these words still often used today? What are more popular now?

Comment: @Tim: I've edited my answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: @Tim: RE your point (1), no it doesn't mean that they are challenging others in any way. "Challenged" here started out as a polite way of saying "below average" or "deficient". As in FumbleFingers comment, instead of saying someone was stupid, you would say "Bob is, umm, let's say intellectually-challenged." It's not that his intellect challenged anyone. Just the opposite. It just sounds nicer than saying "Bob is intellectually deficient". Likewise instead of saying someone was lazy you might say he was "motivation-challenged", etc. (continued)

Comment: (continued) But it came to be something of a cliche, and people started using it as a joke. Like Barrie's example, calling a short person "vertically challenged", or a bald person "follicle challenged". It's not really an insult to say that someone is short or bald, so there was no real need for a polite way to say these things. But it became a joke and people use it for all sorts of things now.

Comment: @Jay: Thanks! How would you say about sleep-deprived? Sleep challenged?

Comment: @Tim: I've never heard anyone described as "sleep challenged". If the problem is imposed by others -- noisy neighbors, interrogators, etc -- I don't think "sleep challenged" would be appropriate. If a person does it to himself, perhaps by excessive worry, then maybe.

Comment: How did this answer get so far without citing "political correctness"?

Comment: @Tim The best one was "vertically challenged" for short people.

Comment: @BenJackson: Which do you mean, the xxx-challenged is political correct or isn't?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Best in what sense? Do you mean when compared to humor-challenged, etc?

Comment: @Tim this thing started out being a politically correct way of saying something, for example, intellectually-challenged as opposed to retarded.  a lot of people think politically correct speak is annoying, so they started to make a joke out of it by *reductio ad absurdum*

Answer (score 6):

It means they lack a sense of humor, being a play on the phrase "mentally challenged", which is one polite way of indicating mental retardation.

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind being "xxxx challenged" is that you struggle personally with "xxxx".  It's a more polite way of mentioning it because it supposedly gives more dignity to the person.  There is a hope of rising above the challenge (as in mentally challenged) vs. something labelled as an "inability" or "handicap".

However, some find the "xxxx challenged" terms patronizing.

The humor behind "humor-challenged" is that it is patronizing in the same way.  It can be used kindly to say, "Don't worry you'll figure out the joke at some point."  But, I've also heard it used to mean that they think you have an inability to understand any kind of humor.

Comment: Thanks! "The humor behind "humor-challenged" is that it is patronizing in the same way." If A calls B humor-challenged, then A is patronizing/condescending. What humor is behind? For example, GEdgar called me humor-challenged in a comment following my original post.

Comment: Unfortunately the humor is for others at your expense.  Unless it's playful teasing among friends.

Answer (score 2):

It generally means that they have trouble recognizing irony, and double meanings. Depending on the context it can also mean that the person lacks a sense of humor in general, as Barry said.

Answer (score 1):

"XXX-challenged" is a form of [political correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness), or a parody of it. It's an exaggerated euphemism for saying someone lacks a sense of humour.